# Bootstrap dropdown disappears on input select

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap dropdown menu I plan to use to login. It appears fine but when I select the username nput it vanishes since the focus has gone to the input. How would I go about adding in support for the inputs or is there a working method for this?

My current code is:

```
    <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" id="drop3" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">Login <b class="caret"></b></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
            <li role="presentation"><input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" /></li>
            <li role="presentation"><input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" /></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
     </li>
```

My attempt at jsfiddle. I couldnt get the dropdown to work at all: http://jsfiddle.net/KF8dv/

Comment: Please add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I was trying but couldn't get the dropdown to respond.Heres the link: http://jsfiddle.net/KF8dv/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please see this :-
http://jsfiddle.net/b8769/

You need to prevent dropdown event when clicked on input text boxes. You can achhive this by using javascript. [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$('.dropdown-menu input').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); //This will prevent the event from bubbling up and close the dropdown when you type/click on text boxes.
    });
```

Comment: Nice!! Quick solution. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: when you write js fiddle for any bootstrap stuffs you can use the bootstrap's CDN path as external urls.. http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: The button seems to pass the click test now and it does not disappear. But after the click if I click somewhere else it will disappear again..